# Javascript regex for validating 12 hour time

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I'm trying to build a 12 hour input component in Javascript and I want to validate the format in real time, as the user types, like a parser validates incoming tokens.

I'm using react, so in each render the field value gets passed trhough the following regex:

```
const validTime = /(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9])\s((a|p|A|P)(m|M))/;
```

I test if the value is valid, if not I add a red border to the input, but with this approach I can write anything, it wouldn't get submitted but you could write something like *ajsjjsdf*, and I'm looking for something different. Allow the user to type only the characters allowed by the regex rule above in real time.

Edit:

I'm adding some code...

Basically the input simpliefied is:

```
<input
  ref={(input) => {this[keyName] = input}}
  className="form-control"
  placeholder="09:00 AM"
  value={scheduleTime ? scheduleTime.value : ''}
  onChange={(ev) => this.onChangeTimeSchedule(ev, keyName)}/>
```

And the value handler:

```
  onChangeTimeSchedule = (ev, scheduleKey) => {
    const validChar = /[0-9]|[aApPmM]|[\s\b]|:/;
    const validTime = /(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9])\s((a|p|A|P)(m|M))/;
    const { value } = ev.target;
    if(!validTime.test(value))
      return;

    const { schedule } = this.state;
    schedule[scheduleKey] = {value, invalid: false};
    this.setState({schedule});
  };
```

if I use validChar it would only allow the characters I want, but it would allow strings like 10:aaaM.

If I use validTime (this is the check I do for each render, to add a red border if invalid) in this context, I always returns false, because it excepts a full match: 10:0 is wrong, 10:00 PM is correct.

Comment: Please post a sample of the **input**

Comment: @PedroLobito updated my question with some code.

Comment: I feel like an easier way might exists, but what if you did an if statement based on the length of the text. Because times are so structured, if the first letter typed is not a 0 or 1 append a 0 to the left of the input. If the length is 2, append a : if the length is 5 append a space. Then base validation on the length of the input. If the char types is invalid for that length, remove the char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it. Set it to case insensitive.

`^(0(?:[1-9]|$)|1(?:[0-2]|$))(?:(:)(?:([0-5])(?:([0-9])(?:(\s)([ap]m?)?)?)?)?)?$`

What you can get with this:

- If group 5 length == 2 (am/pm) the entire time is finished.
- Group 1 contains the partial or full valid data.
- Group 2 contains the hours.
- Group 3 and 4 contain the minute digits (join together).
- Group 5 contains the am/pm.

There are 2 ways to use this regex.

1. As a test for validity. If it does not match, put a red box around the
   edit box and let the user figure out the mistake.
2. As a self correcting match:

   - Take off the last `$` in the regex, allowing a partial match.
   - After every match, write back the group 1 (partial) to the edit box
     thus not allowing invalid entries.
     Wait for a submit button, then validate the entire string (start to finish).

[Formatted](http://www.regexformat.com) / explained :

```
 ^                             # BOS
 (                             # (1 start)
      # Hours
      (                             # (2 start)
           0 
           (?: [1-9] | $ )
        |  1 
           (?: [0-2] | $ )
      )                             # (2 end)


      # Minutes
      (?:
           :                             # ':'
           (?:

                ( [0-5] )                     # (3), Min,digit 1
                (?:
                     ( [0-9] )                     # (4), Min,digit 2
                     (?:
                          \s                            # space
                          (                             # (5 start), AM / PM
                               [ap] m?
                          )?                            # (5 end)
                     )?
                )?

           )?
      )?
 )                             # (1 end)
 $                             # EOS
```

Comment: seems to work, I'll play with it a bit more. Thanks :)

Comment: could you explain to me the use of  '?:' ?

Comment: `(?:..)` is a cluster group (non-capture), this `(?:..)?` makes it's contents optional.