# I need Regex Expression for 12 hours date/time format

Tags: javascript, regex

I need Regex Expression for 12 hours date/time format.
I have tried but not working.

```
let startTime = "8/3/2021, 3:40:26 PM"     
if (startTime == "/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/"){
    console.log("valid format")
  } 
else{
   console.log("in-valid format")
  }
```

This above code shows me the invalid format.

Comment: For one thingh, you seem to have missed the `:` characters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531625/javascript-regex-for-validating-12-hour-time Like that?

Comment: Thanks, but Not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this one ?

```js
const date = '8/3/2021, 3:40:26 PM';
const regex = /([0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9]*, [0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]* (PM|AM))/;
const found = date.match(regex);
console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a non regexp solution will work?

```js
const startTime = "8/3/2021, 3:40:26 PM";
const otherTime = new Date(`2021/3/8 14:40:26`).toString();

console.log(`${startTime}:  ${checkTimeString(startTime)}`);
console.log(`${otherTime}:  ${checkTimeString(otherTime)}`);

function checkTimeString(str) {
  const splitted = str.split(/[:\/\-, ]/).filter(v => v.length);

  return splitted.length === 7 && 
    +(splitted[3]) <= 12 && 
    [`AM`, `PM`].includes(splitted[6]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About the pattern that you tried:

- The pattern does not match because for both the day and the month part in the range from 1 to 9 this pattern `0[1-9]` requires a leading zero which is not in the example string `8/3/2021`
- You are also not matching the comma space and time part after it

---

Without using capture groups, making the leading zero's optional and matching a 12 hours format:

```
^(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(?:19|20)\d{2}, (?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/` Match a number 1 to 12 and `/` with an optional zero for [1-9]
- `(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/` Match number 1 to 31 and `/` with an optional zero for [1-9]
- `(?:19|20)\d{2},`  Match either 19 or 20, 2 digits and `,`
- `(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]` Match a time like pattern for 12 hours format
- `[AP]M` Match either `AM` or `PM`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kRNGtZ/1)